# Recursive Java triangles

Tags: java, recursion

I have question how to solve this problem

Consider the following method named printTriangle that recursively outputs a triangular pattern:

```
public static void printTriangle (int s)
{
      if (s < 1) return;
printTriangle (s-1);
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
    System.out.print( "[]");
}
System.out.println ();
}
```

￼Make minor modifications to printTriangle so that the lines of output are reversed from what the original method produces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the line `printTriangle (s-1);` to the end of the method and you'll get what you want. Can you explain why ? :)

Full code:

```
public class Play {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTriangle(5);
    }

    public static void printTriangle (int s)
    {
        if (s < 1) return;
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            System.out.print( "[]");
        }
        System.out.println ();
        printTriangle (s-1);
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[][][][][]
[][][][]
[][][]
[][]
[]
```

Comment: I get weird shapes, not triangle upside down